# Connection SQL Server From Qt(C++) universal string

Tags: c++, sql-server, qt

In the past, i create connection with sql server from Qt-C++, but the string connection, i found sometimes it changes, i use something like this:

```
 QString stringConnection="DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=local;UID=sad;PWD=soc; WSID=.";
```

This string don't probed on SQL Server 2012 and 2014, but my question is, ¿ Is there any structure of the string connection that works in any SQL Server?(I know if the SQL server works with name of instance, i will add the name of instance on the string, and usually change parameters of user and password)', or not exist a universal connection string for SQL server?

Comment: If you are searching for a universal [connection string for SQL Server](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/), So I think it is invalid and it is depended on your specific environment and security settings ;).

Comment: well, i know  if i use a instance, change the field server("SERVER=localhost\\SQLExpress" for example), but i really thinking in field "Driver2, always works Driver={SQL Server }?

Comment: `Driver={SQL Server}` is specified to use in ODBC connections till now, But I'm not sure about future, every things can change in future. ;).

Comment: i ask, because i try decide a create configuration program and i have two options basically, use combobox (using strings like "SQl Server", "SQL Server Native Client", "SQL Server Native Client 10", etc.) or texinput, but i believe prefer the textinput, or what is your opinion?